# PHP DOMDocument and getElementsByTagName questions?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am trying read the h1 value from HTML string like below,

```
<h1>
<a href="http://example.com/?p=5016"> love me for a reason </a>
</h1>
```

I am using the following code but this returns empty value for the title but the content seems to working (next line) ? why

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom_document = new DOMDocument(); // CREATE A NEW DOCUMENT
$dom_document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($row['html'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')); // LOAD THE STRING INTO THE DOCUMENT

$article_titles=$dom_document->getElementsByTagName("h1");
$title = $article_titles->textContent;


//this works fine 
$article_contents=$dom_document->getElementByID("article-single");
$content=$article_contents->textContent;
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title content is empty because `$article_titles` is still a `DOMNodeList`. Since you are getting elements by **tag name** you would expect this will return one or more element as opposed to getting elements by **id**, you would just be expecting just one since they are supposed to be unique.

You must target the `DOMElement` to get the `->textContent` value. You can reach it thru chaining `->item(index_num)`:

```
$article_titles = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName("h1"); // DOMNodeList
$title = $article_titles->item(0)->textContent;
                       //  ^ point to the first item found, it starts at zero
echo $title;
```

If you want to use `foreach`:

```
foreach($dom_document->getElementsByTagName("h1") as $title) {
    echo $title->textContent . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: can you please add the for-each-loop also in-case someone needs to traverse all the items, not just one.

Comment: @mahen3d sure, i added a loop inside the answer